# how to read line sequently using awk

Tags: awk

My file contains this data:

```
Line1 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line2 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line3 2016-03-16 01:42:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line4 2016-03-16 01:42:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line5 2016-03-16 02:12:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line6 2016-03-16 02:12:35 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
```

I need to compare to line at a time like:

```
Line1 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line2 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90

Line2 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line3 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90

Line3 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line4 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90

Line4 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Line5 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
```

Comment: What is the expected output?, Need compare complete lines or only some fields?

Comment: in the second data block, your lines are duplicates of the first two.

Answer (score 2):

Awk, of course, already reads lines sequentially without any extra effort on your part. For this kind of problem where you want to compare information from the current and previous lines, you can use a template such as:

```
$ cat pcl.awk
NR == 1 { prev_line = $0 }

NR > 1 {
    print "Previous: " prev_line
    print "Current: " $0
    print "(Comparison logic here)"
    print ""
    prev_line = $0;
}

$ awk -f pcl.awk pcl.txt
Previous: Line1 2016-03-16 01:12:26 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Current: Line2 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
(Comparison logic here)

Previous: Line2 2016-03-16 01:22:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Current: Line3 2016-03-16 01:42:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
(Comparison logic here)

Previous: Line3 2016-03-16 01:42:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Current: Line4 2016-03-16 01:42:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
(Comparison logic here)

Previous: Line4 2016-03-16 01:42:36 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Current: Line5 2016-03-16 02:12:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
(Comparison logic here)

Previous: Line5 2016-03-16 02:12:25 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
Current: Line6 2016-03-16 02:12:35 17.70500 83.26889 11.90
(Comparison logic here)
```

Depending on the specifics of the problem at hand, you may want to save one or more specific fields, `$3` e.g., instead of the whole line (`$0`), but the general form of the solution is more or less the same.